# implicit internal interface implementation

Tags: c#, interface, implicit-conversion

When I have a public interface

```
public interface IPub { string Foo { get; set; } }
```

then I can implement this interface either by doing it explicitly:

```
public class CFoo : IPub { string IPub.Foo { get; set; } }
```

or implicitly by using the `public` modifier:

```
public class CFoo : IPub { public string Foo { get; set; } }
```

. Makes sense: The modifier must be `public` because the interface is `public`.

But when I have an internal interface

```
internal interface IInt { string Bar { get; set; } }
```

then I can only implement it explicitly:

```
public class CBar : IInt { string IInt.Bar { get; set; } }
```

or implicitly with the `public` modifier:

```
public class CBar : IInt { public string Bar { get; set; } }
```

, but NOT with the `internal` modifier:

```
public class CBar : IInt { internal string Bar { get; set; } }
// compiler error:
//     'CBar' does not implement interface member 'IInt.Bar'.
//     'CBar.Bar' cannot implement an interface member
//      because it is not public.
```

This make no sense. Why do I need a `public` modifier when the interface is only `internal`? Are there any technical reasons why `public` must always be used in implicit interface implementations, or could the C# developers have made it differently (without needing to change a lot of things in the language)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The modifier must be public because the interface is public.

While that would have been *a* way of determining it: that isn't what the compiler wants. For implicit interface implementation (regardless of the visibility of the interface type), a member must be declared as `public`, no "ifs", "buts" or "maybes" (the *implementing type*, however, can be any visibility level)

Absolutely the language designers *could* have looked at more complex rules, but: since there is also an option for *explicit* interface implementation, they presumably didn't feel that it was necessary to do so.

---

Specifically, this is §18.6.5 ("Interface mapping") in the specification (v5) - emphasis mine ("I"=interface type, "M"=member, "S"=implementing type):

> - If S contains a declaration of an explicit interface member implementation that matches I and M, then
>     this member is the implementation of I.M.
> - Otherwise, if S contains a declaration of a **non-static public member** that matches M, then this member
>     is the implementation of I.M. If more than one member matches, it is unspecified which member is
>     the implementation of I.M. This situation can only occur if S is a constructed type where the two
>     members as declared in the generic type have different signatures, but the type arguments make their
>     signatures identical.